Im trying to iterate a table and extract a value if it has found a value next to it in the table with cypress
I'm trying to iterate a table and extract its value into a variable and use it in another field
The elements are as below
  <tbody>
   <tr class>
     <td class="text-left">Transaction Type </td>
     <td class="text-left">0 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class>
     <td class="text-left">STAN </td>
     <td class="text-left">009466 </td>
   </tr>

I want to extract the numeric value when it finds the STAN value, and am using this code
  cy.get('tbody tr').each(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).within(() => {
      cy.get('td').eq(1).should('contain.text', 'STAN') // contains() doesn't work
    })
  })

I have used the following script but it is failing and i know its not finished.  Please could someone help me find the STAN and extract its value to a variable.

So after some work this is the answer that works:
cy.get('table tbody tr td').each(ele => {
 if(ele.text()==="STAN"){
   let value  = ele.next().text();
   cy.get('.text-primary > .q-breadcrumbs__el').click();
   cy.wait(2000);
   cy.get('div[class="q-pa-md"]').find("input:eq(5)").type(value);
   }
});


Using cy.wait(2000) is bad practice. If that works now, it can be flaky later. Instead use .should() assertion on something on the page that appears after click.

Also, the question is badly presented - where is the click in the code posted?

I agree with @V.Krieps, your answer may work now but could prove unreliable in the future depending on network speeds, etc - when you use a hard wait you can't really be sure you have picked the right waiting time. You might end up with a fail which you find hard to debug, because environment is slowing things down beyond the 2 seconds you chose to wait. Cypress was built to handle environment delays with it's retry feature, so best practice is to instead use cy.get(something).should('be.visible') where something is an element that appears after the click() has finished.

Hi Aladin,  Its failing tho, as its trying to find an element on the screen but never does.  so should the get something automatically wait ?

Why would you pick a something that does not work?

If you know for sure that "STAN" is in the table, you can find it directly, without iteration.
cy.contains('tbody tr', 'STAN')     // get the row with "STAN"
  .find('td').eq(1)                 // it's second column
  .then($el => {
    const text = $el.text()         // extract the text
    const trimmed = text.trim()     // remove the space at the end
    return trimmed
  })
  .as('myValue')                    // save it to an alias  
  .should('eq', '009466')           // just for proof (you may not know the value)

// later in the test
cy.get('@myValue').then(value => {
  ...
})



In your sample HTML there's a space after the value, so I used text.trim() to remove it. Without the .trim() you can get an error due to non-breaking-space (&nbsp;), for example
cy.contains('tbody tr', 'STAN')
  .find('td')
  .eq(1)
  .invoke('text')
  .as('myValue')                  // save to alias  
  .should('eq', '009466')



What if "STAN" might not exist
In a perfect test you would use cy.intercept() to set up the table data, so you know that "STAN" is in the table.
But if that's not possible for some reason, you can check first:
cy.wrap(undefined).as('myValue')             // set up initial alias as undefined

cy.get('tbody tr' )
  .then($rows => {
    const rowWithSTAN = $rows.has('td:contains(STAN)')  // non-failing query
    if (rowWithSTAN.length) {                            // check the result

      cy.wrap(rowWithSTAN)                         // as per above example
        .find('td')
        .eq(1)
        .then($el => {
          const text = $el.text()     
          const trimmed = text.trim() 
          return trimmed
        })
        .as('myValue')                  
        .should('eq', '009466')
    }
  })
  
// later in the test
cy.get('@myValue').then(value => {
  if (value) {
    // only if not undefined
  }
})

The line $rows.has('td:contains(STAN)') is saying - filter the rows to get only the row that has <td> that has "STAN" in the text.

Hi Aladin,  Firstly,  thank you your response,  So i will assume that the STAN will always exist, as it should do.  So i have taken your first section of code and added the following code as i need to take the value of the STAN and type it into a search field, but the value  of the search field entered is not defined.  Do you know what i could be doing wrong,  this is the additional code i am using.

.as('myValue')                    // save it to an alias
  cy.get('.text-primary > .q-breadcrumbs__el').click();   

cy.get('@myValue').then((myValue) => {  
    cy.get('div[class="q-pa-md"]').find("input:eq(5)").type(myValue);
    })


The test passes with the HTML sample given as you can see from the screenshot. If cy.get('@myValue').then(value =>  yields undefined there must be a difference in the page you are testing and the HTML you have shown. Is there any difference you can see?

Do you have the right selector for cy.get('div[class="q-pa-md"]').find("input:eq(5)")? What happens if you use cy.get('div[class="q-pa-md"]').find("input:eq(5)").type("dummyValue"), does it get typed into the field?

Hi Aladin,  its putting it in the right field,  its just the value is not defined that i am getting from the previous screen,  maybe its something about the table im getting it from

Ok, so if you add a .should('eq', '009466') after the .as('myValue')  as I have above, it will confirm that the value is going into the alias. If you also put  .should('eq', '009466') after cy.get('@myValue') it will tell you if the alias still has the value following the cy.get('.text-primary > .q-breadcrumbs__el').click();. If it doesn't pass cy.get('@myValue').should('eq', '009466') then the action of the .click() is changing the contents of the alias - in that case, what does the click do? Does it reload the page?

If on the other hand you are performing cy.get('div[class="q-pa-md"]').find("input:eq(5)").type(myValue); in a second test, the alias won't work since they are cleared down between tests.

Hi Aladin,  The thing is the  value will no always eq 009466,  everytime i run the test the number will change.  The click takes you back to the previous and then im entering the NEW STAN and entering it into a search field.  hope that makes sense.  Just as a side not the .should('eq', '009466') is not failing when i entered it in,

Makes sense that it's not always 009466 otherwise you wouldn't have to run the query to find the value. When you say "the value is not defined that I am getting from the previous screen" - does that mean the alias has lost it's value after the click?

Hi Aladin, I dont think it got it in the first place,  see my answer below that works
